# PHP puts random numbers in directory names. Why?

Tags: php, random, mkdir

I'm trying to create a directory in PHP using mkdir () . It works but PHP puts random numbers in the end of the name:

```
mkdir (testdir);
```

creates a directory testdir511. Is there any way to fix this ?

Comment: It should not, the  problem lies elsewhere. Can you post some code.

Comment: Unless you have a constant defined, that's not very valid PHP code to begin with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've probably used `.` (the concatenation thingy) instead of a comma when separating your arguments:

```
$ php
<?php
mkdir("test" . 655); // should be mkdir("test", 655);
?>
$ ls
test655/
```